# Angular 7: Can't bind to 'messages' since it isn't a known property of 'message-list'

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and trying to build a hobby chat project in Angular 7 as a part of my learning. I am really stuck in understanding modules and components, which ran me into one problem.

**Problem**

I have two components `message-list` and `message-item` as shown in tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/chatbot-with-angular-5-dialogflow-fdac97fef681). I don't want to copy everything from there but only interested in understanding the concept of message list and item.

However i wrote some code below and message-list is not working.

*models/message.ts*

```
export class Message {

    avatar: string;
    content: string;
    timestamp: string;

    constructor( avatar: string, content: string, timestamp: string ){

        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.content = content;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;

    }
}
```

*message-list.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from '../models/message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-list',
  templateUrl: './message-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-list.component.css']
})
export class MessageListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('messages')
  private messages : Message[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*message-list.component.html*

```
<div class="chatlist">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <message-item *ngFor="let msg of messages" [message]="msg"></message-item>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*message-item.component.html*

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <img [src]="message.avatar" class="avatar"/>
  <div class="message">
    {{message.content}}
  </div>
  <div class="timeform">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="timestamp">at {{message.timestamp | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

*message-item.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from '../models/message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-item',
  templateUrl: './message-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-item.component.css']
})
export class MessageItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('message')
  private message: Message;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChatWindowComponent } from './chat-window/chat-window.component';
import { MessageListComponent } from './message-list/message-list.component';
import { MessageItemComponent } from './message-item/message-item.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChatWindowComponent,
    MessageListComponent,
    MessageItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But when i run this program in chrome i get:

[image]

**What I tried**

Spent 2 hours reading and only reading about how to use modules and components but i was not even able to write one line of code because felt so confused, hence i came here to ask this

**What I want**

I would be really glad if at this point i can make my chat app to display messages in this style like it is explained in tutorial link above:

[image]

I would be glad if someone can point me in right direction :) thank you.

Cheers!

Comment: Try making the property public: `@Input() public messages : Message[];

`.

Comment: Make messages public, it should help.

Comment: i made it public, still the same :/

Comment: Check this app on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ji7cmq

Comment: @Sebastian: wow. i was actually looking to implement something similar, but decided to do it tomorrow. thanks for the tip. i will consider your link as my reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't bind to 'messages' since it isn't a known property of 'message-list'

But component has selector `<app-message-list>` here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-list',
  ...
```

In tutorial all those selectors for components are without `app` prefixes, but, when components where generated by `ng cli` the default prefixes (`app`) were added to the selectors. Try to change it in your template to:

```
<app-message-list>
```

Or change here in meta data for component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'message-list',
  ...
```

Comment: i have updated the question. could you just have a quick look. added some missing codes

Comment: silly me! yes you are right. i was using `message-list` instead of `app-message-list`. I had another component where i was supposed to use message list and it was responsible for displaying it on front page. oh gosh!

Answer (score 0):

The `@Input() private messages: Message[];` must be `public` instead of `private` to be accessed outside from your `MessageListComponent`.

Comment: Do you use your component like this: `<app-message-list [messages]="messages"></app-message-list>` ?

Comment: sorry. i forgot to add `message-item` component codes. please see the missing sections i just updated